# How to extract information about UI elements in an android app at runtime?

Tags: android, android-view, accessibility

Hierarchy Viewer lets you extract information about the UI elements by connecting your phone to the laptop. It works by polling the Window Manager/View Manager for information via adb.

I was wondering if it is possible to extract UI information of the foreground screen on the phone at runtime using a background service?

I am trying to build an accessibility service (similar to Talkback), and was trying to find a way to collect information about all the UI elements (their class (e.g. button) and location) on the active foreground screen. I have been able to make an accessibility service, but I have not been able to find a way to get the UI info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find an answer to my problem.

The Android accessibility API provides this functionality. I was able to implement an Accessibility Service and for each accessibility event, I was able to use the [Accessibility Node Info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html) functions, which is essentially a tree representation of all the UI elements on the foreground screen. For example A linear layout consists of a button and an image, then the button and the image would be children for the LL.

The root of the tree can be found by:

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode = getRootInActiveWindow();
```

Then I was able to traverse the tree (Breadth first search) using the `getChild()` function which gives me a list of all the UI elements on the active screen.

Hope it helps someone else too!

Comment: Hi, is it possible to get image content from imageview?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some code and works fine, maybe it's what you want.

Firstly, get the content view:

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

Then use a method to check every element of the parent view:

```
private void showViewInfo(View view){
    if(view instanceof ViewGroup){

        //do something when find view group:
        System.out.println(view.getClass().toString()+"\tx:"+view.getX()+"\ty:"+view.getY());


        for(int i=0;i<((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount();i++){
            showViewInfo(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
    }else{

        //do something when find children
        System.out.println(view.getClass().toString()+"\tx:"+view.getX()+"\ty:"+view.getY());
    }
}
```

Finally, call the method with the parent view as parameter:

```
showViewInfo(parent);
```

and you can get something like this:

```
System.out: class android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout  x:0.0   y:0.0
```

Here is whole code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    showViewInfo(parent);
}

private void showViewInfo(View view){
    if(view instanceof ViewGroup){
        //do something when find view group:
        System.out.println(view.getClass().toString()+"\tx:"+view.getX()+"\ty:"+view.getY());
        //find the children
        for(int i=0;i<((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount();i++){
            showViewInfo(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
    }else{
        //do something when find children
        System.out.println(view.getClass().toString()+"\tx:"+view.getX()+"\ty:"+view.getY());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This works for my own app (when my activity is open), but not when any other app is open on Android. Am I missing something?